# how to use JSX modules in React Typescript app (TSX)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, jsx, tsx

Hi im using https://github.com/hashlips-lab/nft-erc721-collection for a collection im working on.. now that im done with contract part.. im looking to modify the dapp on this repo.. the problem is that its based on TSX files.. and when i try to add any component made in jsx extension, it fails.. can anyone please help me get started and help me guide on where to begin? please

all the tutorials ive found on youtube or elsewhere.. the templates and modules i get are based in jsx format.. and they never seem to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`TSX` is nothing but `JSX` with typescript, so to work on this file, you just need to learn how to use typescript in React. As you already know how to work with `JSX`, it will be very easy for you.
You can check out a crush courses tutorial like this one on react typescript or anything similar to this one, and it will be very clear to you how to work with `TSX`:

[React with TypeScript Crash Course](https://youtu.be/jrKcJxF0lAU)

I hope it's helpful to you.